# Callback url not working on iPod

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, ipod

I am facing an issue regarding a callback Url. It's working on `iPhone`, but not on `iPod`. From the app, I am opening Safari ; on Safari, it is showing the login page, but after login, it will not come back to the app. This issue is observed on `iPod` - both devices having same `iOS` version. Anybody has an idea why it is behaving like this?

Comment: Please ensure both have the same app with the correct URL scheme registered. I don't think URL scheme can work on one and fail on the other.

Comment: The same app launching on both device. Not doing any changes in code.

Comment: It might be an issue of network connection. Make sure that both the devices are connected to same network, and there is not any issue loading pages from Internet.

Comment: Its not network problem. As I investigating this issue. I found some issue like 1)  - (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application handleOpenURL:(NSURL *)url;   // Will be deprecated at some point, please replace with:
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application openURL:(NSURL *)url sourceApplication:(NSString *)sourceApplication annotation:(id)annotation NS_AVAILABLE_IOS(4_2); // no equiv. notification. return NO if the application can't open for some reason

Comment: Hi @SunilTarge .... I am also facing the same issue...did you solve that ?